# PHP Regex extract key-value comma separated

Tags: php, regex

I want to extract some  from a string that KEYs are separated from VALUEs by colon(:) and s separated by comma(,). The problem is that VALUEs can contain comma.
As an example:

```
category:information technology, computer,publisher:Elsevier (EV),subject:Ecology, Evolution, Behavior and Systematics
```

In this example the KEYs that must extract are: category, publisher and subject.
The final result must be as follow:

```
category = information technology, computer
publisher = Elsevier (EV)
subject = Ecology, Evolution, Behavior and Systematics
```

I tried to write a recursive regex but it doesn't work :

```
(category|publisher|subject):(.*?)(?:,(?R)|.?)
```

Can someone help to solve this problem. Thanks.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Well, if you can add a comma to the end of the string, I think this works:

```
(\w+):([^:]+),
```

Edit:

Jonathan Kuhn is totally right:

```
(\w+):([^:]+)(?:,|$)
```

This works

Comment: If you replaced the trailing comma with `(?:,|$)` it would match a comma or the end of the string in a non-grouping match. Eliminating the need to add a comma to the end of the string. https://regex101.com/r/gG9kF3/1

Comment: Thanks. this regex works correctly but can you analyse below regex that also works : 
(\b\w+):(.*?(?=,\w+:|$))