# Extract string containing comma-separated tags from page with regex/python3/bs4

Tags: python, regex, beautifulsoup

I'm parsing a website with BeautifulSoup4 and trying to extract a list of tags in a div presented on a page that look like `tag1, tag2, tag with space, tag-with-hypen, tag3`. There's a wide enough variation of tags that I can't target them directly. Despite my best efforts, I've been unable to create a regex expression that fits my needs.

Some expressions I've tried:

```python
r'((\w[ -]?)+(, )?){14,}'
r'(\w+):([^:]+)(?:,|$)'    # https://stackoverflow.com/a/35495165/3722806
```

What am I missing here?

**EDIT:** To clarify, I'm not dealing with HTML tags like `<b>`, etc. I'm dealing with tags in the sense of "sci-fi," "non-fiction," etc.

Comment: *...tag with space...*. Are you sure that HTML tag might contain space? How in this case browser will know that it is a second part of tag, but not an attribute? Share source code sample and current/desired output

Comment: It's unlikely that it's a tag as mentioned by @Andersson. *Please*, please don't parse HTML with regex. But If you're doing this, you're living in the state of sin and deserve whatever happens to you. People have warned against this.  

Parsing only attributes is fine. Share an HTML example with us.

Comment: I'm not parsing the HTML itself with regex, I'm trying to extract text from a (known by div classes) part of the page. So there's a `div.info` which contains, for example, a description paragraph, author information, and a series of tags (i.e. "non-fiction," "sci-fi," etc.). However, all that text is in one "chunk," so-to-speak, so I'm trying to extract _just_ the list of tags.

Comment: Please, update your question with this `div` you are trying to extract "tags" from.

Comment: Give us at least a screenshot of the content 'tags'

Answer (score -1):

It ended up being simpler than I thought.

```
\S.*, .*
```

Ignore whitespace, find anything separated by a comma, plus the last item.